# HTML Parser on XML page, getting a dictionary of data

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an xml page with information as follows:

```
<currency xmlns:xxsi>
<Observation>
    <Currency_name>U.S. dollar </Currency_name>
    <Observation_ISO4217>USD</Observation_ISO4217>
    <Observation_date>2015-03-09</Observation_date>
    <Observation_data>1.2598</Observation_data>
    <Observation_data_reciprocal>0.7938</Observation_data_reciprocal>
</Observation>
<Observation>
    <Currency_name>U.S. dollar </Currency_name>
    <Observation_ISO4217>USD</Observation_ISO4217>
    <Observation_date>2015-03-11</Observation_date>
    <Observation_data>1.2764</Observation_data>
    <Observation_data_reciprocal>0.7835</Observation_data_reciprocal>
</Observation>
<Observation>
    <Currency_name>Argentine peso</Currency_name>
    <Observation_ISO4217>ARS</Observation_ISO4217>
    <Observation_date>2015-03-09</Observation_date>
    <Observation_data>0.1438</Observation_data>
    <Observation_data_reciprocal>6.9541</Observation_data_reciprocal>
</Observation>
<Observation>
    <Currency_name>Argentine peso</Currency_name>
    <Observation_ISO4217>ARS</Observation_ISO4217>
    <Observation_date>2015-03-10</Observation_date>
    <Observation_data>0.1440</Observation_data>
    <Observation_data_reciprocal>6.9444</Observation_data_reciprocal>
</Observation>
</currency>
```

I want a way to process the data so I can get information out of it, such as if I wanted to compare the two dates of the same currency, or if I want to compare the currency of two different countries. The problem I am having is trying to get that information into a dictionary as a good way to store it.

I am using the following code currently, but it wont work due to the multiple data of the same countries. The actual page has five (5) of the same countries for every country (total of 57)

```
class myHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.country = []
    self.data = []  
    self.dic = {}
    self.nameFlag = False

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'currency_name':
        self.nameFlag = True
    else:
        self.nameFlag = False

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    pass

def handle_data(self, data):
    if data.strip() != '' and self.nameFlag == True:
        self.dic[data.strip()] = []
```

Can someone help me get a good way to store the data for multiple countries?

Comment: Oh, I was told it was. Either way, do you have advice?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux please don't remove the python tag -- just add python-3.x tag if it applies.  Some people only look for the python tag in their searches and removing the tag would remove the question from the results.

Comment: @jedwards My mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have nested elements in your markup language, you can start from a simple parser like that:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.content = []
        self.observation = False
        self.element = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print(tag)
        if tag == 'observation':
            self.content.append({})
            self.observation = True
        elif self.observation:
            self.element = tag
            self.content[-1][self.element] = ""

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'observation':
            self.observation = False

        self.element = None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.element:
            self.content[-1][self.element] += data

from pprint import pprint

with open("data.someml", "rt") as infile:
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(infile.read())

    pprint(parser.content)
```

Given your input file, this will produce:

```
[{'currency_name': 'U.S. dollar ',
  'observation_data': '1.2598',
  'observation_data_reciprocal': '0.7938',
  'observation_date': '2015-03-09',
  'observation_iso4217': 'USD'},
 {'currency_name': 'U.S. dollar ',
  'observation_data': '1.2764',
  'observation_data_reciprocal': '0.7835',
  'observation_date': '2015-03-11',
  'observation_iso4217': 'USD'},
 {'currency_name': 'Argentine peso',
  'observation_data': '0.1438',
  'observation_data_reciprocal': '6.9541',
  'observation_date': '2015-03-09',
  'observation_iso4217': 'ARS'},
 {'currency_name': 'Argentine peso',
  'observation_data': '0.1440',
  'observation_data_reciprocal': '6.9444',
  'observation_date': '2015-03-10',
  'observation_iso4217': 'ARS'}]
```

The key idea here is to create a new record (as a dictionary) each time we encounter an `observation` start tag. Given the assumption explained before, any other start tag will introduce a data field.

Comment: Trying this way I get an out of range error here: self.content[-1][self.element] = "". Would this be because the file might have a nested element?

Comment: @Torched90 All I can say is that was working given your sample data.

Comment: Oh, I figured out why it doesn't work. I forgot to include the first tag that appears before the observation tag. Theres another opening tag of <currency xmlns:xxsi> and a closing one of </currency>

Comment: My bad. So that first tag is what's stopping it from working. Everything as shown above is indented between the first and last tag.

Comment: @Torched90 (1) I took the liberty to edit your question to add the missing tags. Feel free to revert that if you will (2) I've edited my answer to provide a slightly modified version of the parser that work with your XML data. Please, consider that as a _starting point_.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into your code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about *how* you parse the XML, I'd suggest using [Martin Blech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113643/martin-blech)'s [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) module.

Since your file is missing a single document element, you'll need to coax it into cooperating with something like:

```
import xmltodict

with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    d = xmltodict.parse("<root>" + data + "</root>")

d = d['root']
```

Then you could access the XML structure using things like:

```
print(d['Observation'][0]['Currency_name'])     # U.S. dollar
print(d['Observation'][0]['Observation_date'])  # 2015-03-09
```

Or, to loop over all the observations:

```
for obs in d['Observation']:
    print(obs['Currency_name'])
    print(obs['Observation_date'])
    print(obs['Observation_data'])
    print('---')
```

Output:

```
U.S. dollar
2015-03-09
1.2598
---
U.S. dollar
2015-03-11
1.2764
---
Argentine peso
2015-03-09
0.1438
---
Argentine peso
2015-03-10
0.1440
---
```